# Why has my code become recursive within form1?

Tags: c#, winforms, recursion, out-of-memory

I've been working on a bit of software in c# and it was going nicely but as of yesterday evening I noticed that it was throwing a memory exception error at the point when it loads an image. 
I tried to decrease the image size but then realised that 'declaring rats' was being printed repeatedly to the console, where it should only occur once.

Digging a little deeper with some break points I found that it enters the drawing constructor at `allRats = new Drawing(HousePicBox, DekuPicBox, BakuPicBox); //THIS HAS BECOME RECURSIVE, WTF` 
yet it doesn't seem to run the code within the constructor, but jumps back to the start of form1().

I have included all of the code within the files which the Program Counter touches.

//---------------------------------------------------FORM1.CS-------------------------------------------------------------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// This is the code for your desktop app.
// Press Ctrl+F5 (or go to Debug > Start Without Debugging) to run your app.

namespace XMLRats5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // These are here as they are referred to by various functions for different reasons 
        string MazakSourceURL = "http://mtconnect.mazakcorp.com:5609";      // Gives us a human friendly reference to the HTML 
        string NISTSourceURL = "https://smstestbed.nist.gov/vds/current";  // Gives us a human friendly reference to the HTML 

    public PollTimer statusPoller;

    public static Drawing allRats;

    ImageRat Deku;
    ImageRat Bakugo;

    NISTDataSet CurrentNIST;
    MazakDataSet CurrentMazak;


    public Form1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Declaring Rats..."); // Is being called recursively :( ?????????????
        ImageRat.Deku = new Rat(false, 0, 0, true, 0); // Declares Deku
        ImageRat.Bakugo = new Rat(false, 800, 0, true, 0); // Declares Bakugo
        Console.WriteLine("Initialising");
        InitializeComponent(); // Constructs the graphics which make up the 'state 0'   
        Console.WriteLine("Declaring image");
        allRats = new Drawing(HousePicBox, DekuPicBox, BakuPicBox); //THIS HAS BECOME RECURSIVE, WTF
        Console.WriteLine("Clearing Image");
        allRats.ClearRats();
        Console.WriteLine("Displaying House");
        HousePicBox.Show();
        //allRats.DrawRats(ImageRat.deku.Awake, ImageRat.bakugo.Awake);    
        Console.WriteLine("Form 1 Initiated, please proceed.");
    }

    private void NISTDataLinkLabel_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This link takes you to the 'current' NIST testbed data feed page
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(NISTSourceURL);
    }

    private void MAZAKDataLinkLabel_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This link takes you to the raw XML published by Mazaks HCN6800 labelled 5609
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(MazakSourceURL);
    }

    public void StatusCheckButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Here we should check that the machine tools are feeding live data
    {
        // Clear the rat picture boxes as they 'stick' when already shown
        DekuPicBox.Hide();
        BakuPicBox.Hide();

        string MazakStatus = "Unchecked";
        string NISTStatus = "Unchecked";


        try
        {
            CurrentMazak = MTFunctions.PollMazak();
            MazakStatus = CurrentMazak.Status;
            if (MazakStatus == "AVAILABLE") { ImageRat.Deku.Awake = true; }
        }
        catch (Exception MazakLookupFailed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not retrieve Mazak Data", MazakLookupFailed);
            MazakStatus = "Lookup Failed"; // This will later refer to the xml path for running status 
        }


        try
        {
            CurrentNIST = MTFunctions.PollNIST();
            NISTStatus = CurrentNIST.Status;
            if (NISTStatus == "AVAILABLE") { ImageRat.Bakugo.Awake = true; }
        }
        catch (Exception NISTLookupFailed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not Retrieve NIST Data: ", NISTLookupFailed);
            NISTStatus = "Lookup Failed";
            ImageRat.Bakugo.Awake = false;
        }

        string MessageString = " Mazak : " + MazakStatus + "\n NIST     : " + NISTStatus;

        if ((ImageRat.Deku.Awake == true) & (ImageRat.Bakugo.Awake == true))   // Both Online
        {
            HousePicBox.Image = XMLRats5.Properties.Resources.bothsleep; // SLeeping rat shows machine online but not feeding data

        } // Empty Box
        if ((ImageRat.Deku.Awake == true) & (ImageRat.Bakugo.Awake == false))  // NIST offline 
        {
            HousePicBox.Image = XMLRats5.Properties.Resources.bakusleep;
            DekuPicBox.Show(); // Not neccessary but prevents bugs
        } // Put Bakug in box, deku out
        if ((ImageRat.Deku.Awake == false) & (ImageRat.Bakugo.Awake == true))  // Mazak Offline
        {
            HousePicBox.Image = XMLRats5.Properties.Resources.dekuSleep;
            BakuPicBox.Show(); // Not neccessary but prevents bugs
        } // Put deku in box, bakugo out
        if ((ImageRat.Deku.Awake == false) & (ImageRat.Bakugo.Awake == false)) // Both Offline
        {
            HousePicBox.Image = XMLRats5.Properties.Resources.nosleep;
        } // Put rats in box


        MessageBox.Show(MessageString, "Machine Status"); // We need to pass information gained through XPath to first argument            
    }

    public void WakeRatsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This 'wakes the rats' (Begins data stream)");
        // We need to poll Mazak and NIST here to determine which images to draw.
        MazakDataSet checkM = MTFunctions.PollMazak();
        NISTDataSet checkN = MTFunctions.PollNIST();
        if (checkM.Status == "AVAILABLE")
        {
            ImageRat.Deku.Awake = true;
            DekuPicBox.Show();
        }
        else { ImageRat.Deku.Awake = false; }
        if (checkN.Status == "AVAILABLE")
        {
            BakuPicBox.Show();
            ImageRat.Bakugo.Awake = true;
        }
        else { ImageRat.Bakugo.Awake = false; }


        allRats.DrawRats(ImageRat.Deku.Awake, ImageRat.Bakugo.Awake); // Should move the boys out of the box
        // Here the draw function successfully relocates the rats, so why does this not work from the timer?

        statusPoller = new PollTimer(2000, true); //Initiate a timer driven function which polls the data sets
        // Timer Driven function draws rats
    }

    public void DebugInstructionsLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }

    public void titleLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

    public void SleepRatsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This 'puts the rats to bed' (Closes data stream)");

        try  // Stop Polling timer function
        {
            statusPoller.Stop();
            statusPoller.Dispose();
            Console.Write("Stream closed successfully");
        }
        catch { Console.WriteLine("Could not stop polling. Were the rats actually 'awake'?"); }

        // Draw rats in house   
        DekuPicBox.Hide(); // Rat is no longer active
        BakuPicBox.Hide(); // Rat is no longer active
        HousePicBox.Image = XMLRats5.Properties.Resources.nosleep; // Show empty box

        //allRats.Paint();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void HousePicBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void DekuPicBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Proves that problem with movement is because DekuPicBox needs to be changed, not allRats.dekuPic....
        System.Drawing.Point DekuCoord = new System.Drawing.Point(ImageRat.Deku.PosX, ImageRat.Deku.PosY);      // Create a 'System Point' for Deku
        DekuPicBox.Location = DekuCoord;
        Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~~~Deku moved to " + DekuCoord + " ~~~~~~~~");
    }

    private void BakuPicBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Point BakuCoord = new System.Drawing.Point(ImageRat.Bakugo.PosX, ImageRat.Bakugo.PosY);      // Create a 'System Point' for Deku
        BakuPicBox.Location = BakuCoord;
        Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~~~Bakugo moved to " + BakuCoord + " ~~~~~~~~");
    }



    public void Refresh(int boi) // Better bloody relocate those pics boii
    {
        if (boi == 0)
        {
            System.Drawing.Point BakuCoord = new System.Drawing.Point(ImageRat.Bakugo.PosX, ImageRat.Bakugo.PosY);      // Create a 'System Point' for Deku
            DekuPicBox.Location = BakuCoord;
        }
        else
        {
            System.Drawing.Point DekuCoord = new System.Drawing.Point(ImageRat.Deku.PosX, ImageRat.Deku.PosY);      // Create a 'System Point' for Deku
            DekuPicBox.Location = DekuCoord;
        }

    }

}
}
```

//----------------------------------------------FORM1.Designer.CS--------------------------------------------------------

```
namespace XMLRats5
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.MAZAKDataLinkLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel();
        this.DebugInstructionsLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.StatusCheckButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.TitleLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.WakeRatsButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SleepRatsButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.NISTDataLinkLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel();
        this.BakuPicBox = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.HousePicBox = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.DekuPicBox = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.BakuPicBox)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.HousePicBox)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.DekuPicBox)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // MAZAKDataLinkLabel
        // 
        this.MAZAKDataLinkLabel.AutoSize = true;
        this.MAZAKDataLinkLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1287, 985);
        this.MAZAKDataLinkLabel.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 0, 4, 0);
        this.MAZAKDataLinkLabel.Name = "MAZAKDataLinkLabel";
        this.MAZAKDataLinkLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(179, 25);
        this.MAZAKDataLinkLabel.TabIndex = 0;
        this.MAZAKDataLinkLabel.TabStop = true;
        this.MAZAKDataLinkLabel.Text = "View Mazak Data";
        this.MAZAKDataLinkLabel.LinkClicked += new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this.MAZAKDataLinkLabel_LinkClicked);
        // 
        // DebugInstructionsLabel
        // 
        this.DebugInstructionsLabel.AutoSize = true;
        this.DebugInstructionsLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1066, 524);
        this.DebugInstructionsLabel.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 0, 4, 0);
        this.DebugInstructionsLabel.Name = "DebugInstructionsLabel";
        this.DebugInstructionsLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(623, 50);
        this.DebugInstructionsLabel.TabIndex = 1;
        this.DebugInstructionsLabel.Text = "Press \'Check Machine\' to ensure a device is running, otherwise \n don\'t expect muc" +
"h activity from the rats!";
        this.DebugInstructionsLabel.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.DebugInstructionsLabel_Click);
        // 
        // StatusCheckButton
        // 
        this.StatusCheckButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1271, 658);
        this.StatusCheckButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
        this.StatusCheckButton.Name = "StatusCheckButton";
        this.StatusCheckButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(195, 54);
        this.StatusCheckButton.TabIndex = 2;
        this.StatusCheckButton.Text = "Check Machine Status";
        this.StatusCheckButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.StatusCheckButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.StatusCheckButton_Click);
        // 
        // TitleLabel
        // 
        this.TitleLabel.AutoSize = true;
        this.TitleLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 16F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.TitleLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1255, 382);
        this.TitleLabel.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 0, 4, 0);
        this.TitleLabel.Name = "TitleLabel";
        this.TitleLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(211, 51);
        this.TitleLabel.TabIndex = 3;
        this.TitleLabel.Text = "XML Rats";
        this.TitleLabel.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.titleLabel_Click);
        // 
        // WakeRatsButton
        // 
        this.WakeRatsButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1271, 775);
        this.WakeRatsButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
        this.WakeRatsButton.Name = "WakeRatsButton";
        this.WakeRatsButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(195, 54);
        this.WakeRatsButton.TabIndex = 4;
        this.WakeRatsButton.Text = "Wake Rats";
        this.WakeRatsButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // SleepRatsButton
        // 
        this.SleepRatsButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1271, 885);
        this.SleepRatsButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
        this.SleepRatsButton.Name = "SleepRatsButton";
        this.SleepRatsButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(195, 54);
        this.SleepRatsButton.TabIndex = 5;
        this.SleepRatsButton.Text = "Sleep Rats";
        this.SleepRatsButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // NISTDataLinkLabel
        // 
        this.NISTDataLinkLabel.AutoSize = true;
        this.NISTDataLinkLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1287, 1054);
        this.NISTDataLinkLabel.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 0, 4, 0);
        this.NISTDataLinkLabel.Name = "NISTDataLinkLabel";
        this.NISTDataLinkLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(162, 25);
        this.NISTDataLinkLabel.TabIndex = 6;
        this.NISTDataLinkLabel.TabStop = true;
        this.NISTDataLinkLabel.Text = "View NIST Data";
        // 
        // BakuPicBox
        // 
        this.BakuPicBox.Image = global::XMLRats5.Properties.Resources.bakuTransSmall;
        this.BakuPicBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(2092, 1388);
        this.BakuPicBox.Name = "BakuPicBox";
        this.BakuPicBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(632, 424);
        this.BakuPicBox.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        this.BakuPicBox.TabIndex = 9;
        this.BakuPicBox.TabStop = false;
        // 
        // HousePicBox
        // 
        this.HousePicBox.Image = global::XMLRats5.Properties.Resources.nosleep;
        this.HousePicBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1057, 1388);
        this.HousePicBox.Name = "HousePicBox";
        this.HousePicBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(632, 424);
        this.HousePicBox.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        this.HousePicBox.TabIndex = 8;
        this.HousePicBox.TabStop = false;
        // 
        // DekuPicBox
        // 
        this.DekuPicBox.Image = global::XMLRats5.Properties.Resources.DekuBackgroundTransparent;
        this.DekuPicBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 1388);
        this.DekuPicBox.Name = "DekuPicBox";
        this.DekuPicBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(632, 424);
        this.DekuPicBox.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        this.DekuPicBox.TabIndex = 7;
        this.DekuPicBox.TabStop = false;
        this.DekuPicBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.DekuPicBox_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(12F, 25F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(2736, 1824);
        this.Controls.Add(this.BakuPicBox);
        this.Controls.Add(this.HousePicBox);
        this.Controls.Add(this.DekuPicBox);
        this.Controls.Add(this.NISTDataLinkLabel);
        this.Controls.Add(this.SleepRatsButton);
        this.Controls.Add(this.WakeRatsButton);
        this.Controls.Add(this.TitleLabel);
        this.Controls.Add(this.StatusCheckButton);
        this.Controls.Add(this.DebugInstructionsLabel);
        this.Controls.Add(this.MAZAKDataLinkLabel);
        this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.BakuPicBox)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.HousePicBox)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.DekuPicBox)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel MAZAKDataLinkLabel;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label DebugInstructionsLabel;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button StatusCheckButton;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label TitleLabel;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button WakeRatsButton;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button SleepRatsButton;
    private System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel NISTDataLinkLabel;
    public System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox DekuPicBox;
    public System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox HousePicBox;
    public System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox BakuPicBox;
}
```

}

//-------------------------------------------------------------DRAWING.CS----------------------------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace XMLRats5
{
    public class Drawing : Form1
    {
        private PictureBox HouseImage;
        private PictureBox DekuImage;
        private PictureBox BakuImage;

        public Drawing(PictureBox house, PictureBox deku, PictureBox baku)
        {
            HouseImage  = house;
            DekuImage   = deku;
            BakuImage   = baku;
        } // Code is jumping back to form1 call :S


        public void ClearRats()
        {
            //DekuImage.Image.Dispose();
            //BakuImage.Image.Dispose();
            //HouseImage.Image.Dispose();

            HouseImage.Hide();
            DekuImage.Hide();
            BakuImage.Hide();
        }

        public void RePaint()
        {
            //BakuImage.Paint();
            //DekuImage.Paint();
            //HouseImage.Paint();
        }

        public void DrawRats(bool DekuWake, bool BakuWake) // Call this function using active status of 2 machines
        {
            this.ClearRats();

            DekuPicBox.SuspendLayout();
            BakuPicBox.SuspendLayout();
            HousePicBox.SuspendLayout();

            System.Drawing.Point DekuCoord = new System.Drawing.Point(ImageRat.Deku.PosX, ImageRat.Deku.PosY);      // Create a 'System Point' for Deku
            System.Drawing.Point BakuCoord = new System.Drawing.Point(ImageRat.Bakugo.PosX, ImageRat.Bakugo.PosY);  // Create a 'System Point' for Bakugo
            Console.WriteLine("Randomly Generated Point Assigned (Deku):" + DekuCoord);
            Console.WriteLine("Randomly Generated Point Assigned (Baku):" + BakuCoord);

            if (DekuWake == false)
            {
                DekuImage.Hide();
                if (BakuWake == false)
                {
                    BakuPicBox.Hide();
                    HousePicBox.Image = XMLRats5.Properties.Resources.bothsleep;// set HouseImage to both sleep
                }
                else
                {
                    BakuPicBox.Location = BakuCoord;                    
                    BakuPicBox.Show();                    
                    HousePicBox.Image = XMLRats5.Properties.Resources.dekuSleep; //Set HouseImage to DekuSleep 
                }
            }
            else //DekuWake == true
            {
                DekuImage.Show();
                if (BakuWake == true)
                {
                    HousePicBox.Image = XMLRats5.Properties.Resources.nosleep;//Set House image to nosleep
                    DekuPicBox.Location = DekuCoord;
                    DekuPicBox.Show();
                    BakuPicBox.Location = BakuCoord;
                    BakuPicBox.Show();
                }    
                else
                {
                    BakuPicBox.Hide();
                    HousePicBox.Image = XMLRats5.Properties.Resources.bakusleep;// Set house image to bakusleep
                    DekuPicBox.Location = DekuCoord;
                    DekuPicBox.Show();
                }
            }

            HousePicBox.Show(); // Out here as it should always happen


        }

    }



}
```

Honestly I'm baffled as to why it keeps jumping back to the start of form1. 
What have I broken?

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside the Form1 constructor in the debugger, let it hit it a few times and then break and inspect the call stack to find out what's happening.

Comment: Usually the problem is you are calling the constructor with new which is creating multiple copies.  To prove this put a break point in the two constructors for Form1 and the inherited Form1 Drawing.  I suspect you have two classes called Drawing.  The Net Library System.Drawing and your own version.   You did not post all the code so I cannot duplicate issue.

Comment: Bugger @PaulF you seem to be right :/ 
I've been struggling to get the image locations to update via a timer and thought this would be a solution as it would allow me to refer to the pictureboxes within form1 from the draw function

Comment: The "jumping" is normal, the constructor of your derived class automatically calls the default constructor of the base class.  "Memory exceptions" are pretty normal as well, you must call Dispose() on any bitmaps you use.  Like the one you get from XMLRats5.Properties.Resources.bothsleep, etc, it is not automatic.  In general when you assign the Image property of a PictureBox then you need to Dispose() the previous one.

Answer (score 3):

As Drawing is derived from Form1 & you create an instance of Drawing in the Form1 constructor - this is going to cause the Form1 constructor to be invoked again which causes the creation of another instance of Drawing which causes ........... -

Note the base class constructor is called before the code in the derived class constructor - which is why you don't get to the code in the Drawing constructor.